# What's the appropriate data structure to hold a group of variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm given a third party function `mk_config` that gives me objects according to a `(key, configs)`. The typical usage is, when you need some of the these objects, you say

```py
args = mk_config('args', **configs)
validator = mk_config('validator', **configs)
postproc = mk_config('postproc', **configs)
```

and then work with said objects.

Since I don't like seeing big blocks of boilerplate, I think, okay, the following might be better:

```py
def mk_configs_tuple(keys, **configs):
    return [mk_config(k, **configs) for k in keys]

args, validator, postproc = mk_configs_tuple(
        ['args', 'validator', 'postproc'],
        **configs)
```

But there's still a repetition of the the key names, and if dealing with 20, this could get out of hand. I could inject these in `locals()` to be D.R.Y., but most would say that's too dry, so I think I could do this:

```py
def mk_configs_dict(keys, **configs):
    return {k: mk_config(k, **configs) for k in keys}

m = mk_configs_dict(['args', 'validator', 'postproc'], **configs)
assert list(m) == ['args', 'validator', 'postproc']
```

Now, dictionaries are fast, but they don't always autosuggest well in IDEs, and it's more cumbersome to write `['']` than `.` (as JSON would). So I think:

```py
def mk_config_obj(keys, **configs):
    class ConfigObj: ...
    config_obj = ConfigObj()
    for key in keys:
        setattr(config_obj, key, mk_config(key, **configs))
    return config_obj

config_obj = mk_config_obj(['args', 'validator', 'postproc'], **configs)
assert {'args', 'validator', 'postproc'}.issubset(dir(config_obj))
```

But then I think if I can't do this with what python comes with naturally, I'm missing somethiing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)?

```
from collections import namedtuple

def mk_config_obj(keys, **configs):
    return namedtuple('ConfigObj', keys)(*[mk_config(key, **configs) for key in keys])
```

Comment: Yes. See my proposed answer so far... 5mn before you. But here's a +1 as a welcome to StackOverflow gesture.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a list of dictionaries sometimes

```
list_of_dictionaries = []

a = {}
s = {}
d = {}
f = {}

list_of_dictionaries.append(a)
list_of_dictionaries.append(s)
list_of_dictionaries.append(d)
list_of_dictionaries.append(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I have so far is:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

def mk_config_nt(keys, **configs):
    ConfigNT = namedtuple('ConfigNT', field_names=keys)
    return ConfigNT(**{k: mk_config(k, **configs) for k in keys})
```

Why I like it?

Because I get my keys as attributes:

```py
config_nt = mk_config_nt(['args', 'validator', 'postproc'], **configs)
assert {'args', 'validator', 'postproc'}.issubset(dir(config_nt))
```

which I can use autosuggest/complete on (though there's two extra annoying method names: `count` and `index`).

Because I still have the choice to do this:

```py
args, validator, postproc = mk_config_nt(['args', 'validator', 'postproc'], **configs)
```

And... it's actually faster than a `dict`, somehow. Key/attribute access timing (on a three item group):

```
custom object:   36.9 ns
dict:   32.4 ns
namedtuple:   30.7 ns
```

Answer (score 0):

Say hello to Enums.

```
from enum import Enum

class MKConfigKey(Enum):
    args = 'args'
    validator = 'validator'
    postproc = 'post-roc'

config_map = {key: mk_config(key.value, **config) for key in MKConfigKey}
```